# How to decide between two numbers randomly using javascript?

Tags: javascript, random

I want a javascript script that choose either value1 or value2 randomly, not between the two values , just the actual values.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The [`Math.random`<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) function chooses a random value in the interval `[0, 1)`. You can take advantage of this to choose a value randomly.

```
var chosenValue = Math.random() < 0.5 ? value1 : value2;
```

Comment: This is a bit pedantic, but it should be `<` or `>=`.  Otherwise, `value1` will be slightly more likely.  This is because `random` returns a number up until but not including `1.0`.

Comment: @Jacob I was trying to figure out which comparison operator to use; thanks. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 33):

`Math.round(Math.random())` returns a 0 or a 1, each value just about half the time.

You can use it like a true or false, 'heads' or 'tails', or as a 2 member array index-

`['true','false'][Math.round(Math.random())]` will return 'true' or 'false'...

Answer (score 5):

```
~~(Math.random()*2) ? true : false
```

This returns either 0 or 1. "~~" is a double bitwise NOT operator. Basically strips the the decimal part. Useful sometimes.

[It is supposed to be faster then Math.floor()](http://rocha.la/JavaScript-bitwise-operators-in-practice)

Not sure how fast it is as a whole. I submitted it just for curiosity :)

Answer (score 2):

```
parseInt(Math.random() * 2) ?  true : false;
```

Comment: It's usually good to add some contextual information explaining your code for a an answer