# Random toggle between classes on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, onload

I have my website divided into 50/50% with each its own look and info. I have a css class that can make the both sides floats left or right depends on what it is set to. I would like to have a small script that
random toggles between classes so on page load and switch to the left or right.

**CSS class now:**

```
.left-wrapper,
.right-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

**I was thinking toggle between two classes:**

```
.left-wrapper-1,
.right-wrapper-1 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}


.left-wrapper-2,
.right-wrapper-2 {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

**Javascript not working:**

```
window.onload = function() {
     $('.left-wrapper-1').toggleClass('left-wrapper-2');
     $('.right-wrapper-1').toggleClass('right-wrapper-2');
};
```

Comment: Open your console and check for javascript errors. I have a feeling that you haven't included the jQuery library to your project.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: You must see it like this when floats set to left it looks like RED/BLACK and when i set it to right it is BLACK/RED. Only the script above doesn't random toggle between them when reloading etc.

Comment: We still must know which errors you get, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pure JavaScript version of @KennyFellows answer:

https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/LwqL1ep1/

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // This is a ternary operator, which is just a shorthand way to 
  // do an if/else statement. This basically says, if the random number
  // is less than .5, assign "1" to the scenario variable.
  // if it is greater (or equal to), assign "2" to the variable. 
  var scenario = Math.random() < .5 ? "1" : "2";

  document.querySelector(".left-wrapper").classList.add("left-wrapper-" + scenario);
  document.querySelector(".right-wrapper").classList.add("right-wrapper-" + scenario);

});
```

```css
.left-wrapper-1,
.right-wrapper-1 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.left-wrapper-2,
.right-wrapper-2 {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-wrapper">1</div>
<div class="right-wrapper">2</div>
```

Comment: Really like the way you are thinking it doesn't work yet.

Comment: @Pallum it works, click 'Run code snippet' multiple times, it will swap the 1 and the 2 ...

Comment: It does!! I was confused with another similar code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Like i understand your question, just try like that :

```
window.onload = function() {
   $('.left-wrapper-1').toggleClass('left-wrapper-1 left-wrapper-2');
   $('.right-wrapper-1').toggleClass('right-wrapper-1 right-wrapper-2');
};
```

It will remove class `left-wrapper-1` from element with `left-wrapper-1` class and add `left-wrapper-2` .

Same for second :
It will remove class `right-wrapper-1` from element with `right-wrapper-1` class and add `right-wrapper-2` .

[$.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) : will remove the class present in `(...)` and add those are not present !

I hope this will help you.

---

Edit : after comments and clarification,

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  // the random part is here
  var id = Math.floor( Math.random() * 2 ) + 1;
  // just for debug
  $('#dbg').append('<div>' + id + '</div>');


     $('.left-wrapper').toggleClass('left-wrapper-' + id);
     $('.right-wrapper').toggleClass('right-wrapper-' + id);

});
```

```css
.left-wrapper,
.right-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.left-wrapper-1,
.right-wrapper-1 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background : red;
}


.left-wrapper-2,
.right-wrapper-2 {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  background : black;
  color : #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='left-wrapper'>A</div>
<div class='right-wrapper'>B</div>
<button>click me</button>
<div id='dbg'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but when reloading it doesn't random toggle between them so i only see BLACK/RED and not visa versa on load.

Comment: because using toggleClass have not random property ! i don't understand what you try to achieve, can you explain precisly ?

Comment: Really simple i have a website design divide into 50%/50% RED/BLACK red= `.left-wrapper` and black= `right-wrapper`. I know when i change the float value for both classes by hand to right it will result into BLACK/RED only thing i want to achieve is that is will randomly will do that on loading page.

Comment: @Pallum : ok ! i have added a snippet working like you want, check it and tell me !

Comment: Thanks mate you code looks great, but i want it on load page. It looks similar to the code that works for me now by @ryanpcmcquen

Comment: yes it seems ! I have focused on the 'randomness', you can use it also with `onload` instead of `onclick`. happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

The current JS you have there won't do a random toggle. It will just find the element with a class of .left-wrapper-1, and add a class of .left-wrapper-2 as well.

You would need something more like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // This is a ternary operator, which is just a shorthand way to 
    // do an if/else statement. This basically says, if the random number
    // is less than .5, assign "1" to the scenario variable.
    // if it is greater (or equal to), assign "2" to the variable. 
    var scenario = Math.random() < .5 ? "1" : "2"; 

    $(".left-wrapper").addClass("left-wrapper-" + scenario); 
    $(".right-wrapper").addClass("right-wrapper-" + scenario); 

});
```

Comment: I like this answer. If you're going to use this, please make sure you set the `div`s initial classes to `left-wrapper` and `right-wrapper` (not `left-wrapper-1` and `right-wrapper-1`).

Comment: This should be the chosen answer.

Comment: Good call, I noticed in the CSS that it does look like those classes are already assigned, but you want to make sure that the styles are not applied to these "default" classes. We really only want to use them for the sake of being able to select these elements. The styles that change should only be assigned to .left-wrapper-1, .left-wrapper-2, and the same for the .right-wrapper-1 and .right-wrapper-2.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
// set a variable and give it a random boolean value
var myRandom = !Math.floor( Math.random() * 2 );

// if true (or false), toggle classes
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (myRandom) {
        $('.left-wrapper-1').toggleClass('left-wrapper-1 left-wrapper-2');
        $('.right-wrapper-1').toggleClass('right-wrapper-1 right-wrapper-2');
    };
});
```

Comment: By the way, [How to decide between two numbers randomly using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9730966/3471286)